# how would I get the sum of all shares using fb jssdk

Tags: javascript, arrays, facebook

I make a call to the facebook graph api  (PageID/feed?fields=shares) and receive this response

```
`    {
       "data": [
       {
         "shares": {
         "count": 1200
       },
       "id": "POST#0 ID GOES HERE"
     },
       {
         "shares": {
         "count": 1100
       },
       "id": "POST#1 ID GOES HERE"
   }
  ],
`
```

I want to iterate through the arrays and get the sum of all shares. (2300 in this example)

If I use     `console.log(response.data[0].shares[0].count[0]);`
I get the right count (1200) but how would I handle this if I have say 20 different "shares"

Comment: Hey, provide some code of what you have triedso far so that we can help you with that. Stack Overflow is not about someone else solving your problems, but rather helping you with doing that on your own.

Comment: why cant you just write your own function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ES6 reduce function to get the result

```js
  const arr = {
    "data": [{
        "shares": {
          "count": 1200
        },
        "id": "POST#0 ID GOES HERE"
      },
      {
        "shares": {
          "count": 1100
        },
        "id": "POST#1 ID GOES HERE"
      }
    ]
  }


  const sharesSum = arr.data.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x.shares.count, 0)
  console.log(sharesSum)
```